# Saving sequence tree from GraphViz

Tags: r, rstudio, graphviz, r-markdown, traminer

I'm new to TraMineR and sequence analysis in general. I am working on a project related to retention and recruitment of educational leaders and finding TraMineR to be very useful. This may be a simple thing (and somewhat unimportant), but I cannot seem to figure out how to name or direct the sequence tree created by GraphViz within the TraMinR package.  Right now, my code is:

```
wardTree=as.seqtree(wardCluster,seqdata=retain.seq,diss=retain.dst,ncluster=15)
seqtreedisplay(wardTree,type="d",border=NA,showdepth=TRUE)
```

It produces a great graphic, but with a random file name that I cannot relocate if I accidentally close the graphic.

My main goal is to be able to uniquely name and save these graphs and pull into an R Markdown for the full project.  To this point, the only thing I cannot pull in is the seqtree graphic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, guess I figured it out! I didn't realize that the order in which filename command mattered...so...what seems to work out beautifully is:

```
wardTree=as.seqtree(wardCluster,seqdata=retain.seq,diss=retain.dst,ncluster=15)
seqtreedisplay(wardTree,type="d",border=NA,showtree=TRUE,showdepth=TRUE,filename="retaintree.png",imageformat="png")
```

And to incorporate the file in the Markdown i use the command

````
```    
![](C:\Users\myname\Desktop\retaintree.png)    
```{r fig.width=8.5, fig.height=11}
````

Hope this helps someone else along the way!

Comment: And, assuming `path` points to an existing folder, you could control for the destination directory by stating `filename="path/retaintree.png"`.